# Guava Cache expireAfterWrite is only applicable with getIfPresent used?

Tags: java, caching, ttl, google-guava-cache, cache-expiration

This question is to validate an observed behavior to ensure Guava Cache is used in correct way.

I have setup two Guava Caches (see code below): with and without a builder - as Guava [documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#when-does-cleanup-happen) states:

> Caches built with CacheBuilder do not perform cleanup and evict values
>   "automatically," or instantly after a value expires, or anything of
>   the sort.

It appears that expiration is only observed if [`getIfPresent()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#getIfPresent-java.lang.Object-) method is used, i.e. when a key is queried then value of `null` is returned after a period of time > expiry interval passes upon key/value is written to the cache. In case of Cache built with CacheLoader using [`get()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#get-K-) or [`getUnchecked()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#getUnchecked-K-) results in `CacheLoader.load()` method to be executed thus expiry is not observed i.e. `null` value is never returned.

Is this the correct expectation?

Thank you for your patience and help.

```
// excerpt from test code

    private static final FakeTicker fakeTicker = new FakeTicker();

    private static LoadingCache<Integer, String> usingCacheLoader = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .expireAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .ticker(fakeTicker)
                    .build(new CacheLoader<Integer, String>() {
                        public String load(Integer keyName) throws Exception {
                            logger.info("Getting value for key: {}", keyName);
                            return getValue(keyName, "with_cache_loader");
                        }
                    });

    private static Cache<Integer, String> withoutCacheLoader = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .expireAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .ticker(fakeTicker)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that if you call get or getUnchecked you will never get null.

The expiration can be "observed" both in terms of performance - how long it takes to get for a specific key and whether it has to be freshly computed - and in whether the actual value you get reflects perhaps out of date information.

Comment: Thank you Louis for confirming this, I appreciate it :)